# C# Simple Game architecture

Tags: c#, forms, window

Im going to make simple game with fallowing architecture:

```
Initialization
OpenWindowAndGraphics
while(game_not_end) {
    ReadEvents
    UpdateData
    RePaint
}
CloseWindow
```

I'm making this in Windows Forms. Firstly i tought that i will make my own Panel. In constructor i will initialize everything, but now i'm not sure where should i make game loop. Game will be simple, but i will extend it as soon as i will make things works. Main class looks like this:

```
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1(sessid,serwer));
```

In the Form1 is only SpecialPanel which have overriden Constructor and OnPain method (to initialize and Draw everything).
So i need to control when Panel is repainting and make game loop. How can i do this?

Comment: It might be worth using XNA. It's pretty simple (I'd say it's simpler then trying to use WinForms) to get a hang of and sets up a similar structure. And it's won't have all the problems of trying to use Forms for games, which it really was never intended to do.

Comment: +1 re. using XNA - it actually makes your life much simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Forms uses GDI+ for rendering. I don't think Windows Forms is a good choice for developing a game unless it is just a matter of interest. Otherwise XNA Game SDK lets you develop games using C# very easily and it provides everything you need to develop a good game. The lifecycle of a Game program you're trying to define is already there in XNA SDK..

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the guide [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/99860-creating-games-in-c%23-part-i/). It will get you started and answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would use XNA to develop a game. The tutorials found on [Riemers's XNA Tutorials](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/xnacsharp.php) helped me a lot in creating a game.